# How to permanently disable pylance toast

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode 1.51.1

MacOS 10.15.7

I'm using the MS python extension. When I open python source code I get this toast:

```
Pylance extension is not installed. Click Yes to open Pylance installation page.
```

The project I'm working on uses python 2, which pylance does not support.  I clicked on No in the toast.  When I open another python file I still get notified to installed pylance.

Is there a way to disable this toast?

Comment: change the setting to `"python.languageServer": "Microsoft"`

Comment: @rioV8 that worked.  consider replying so you can get credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python Language Server used is determined by the setting `python.languageServer`

The 2 possible values are:

- `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"`
- `"python.languageServer": "Microsoft"`

If you change the setting to `"Microsoft"` it stops messaging about Pylance.

The setting can be in the global `settings.json` or the Workspace `.vscode/settings.json`

**Edit**

Recently 2 more options have been added

- `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"`
- `"python.languageServer": "JediLSP"`